# Python .splitlines() to segment text into separate variables

Tags: python-2.7

I've read the other threads on this site but haven't quite grasped how to accomplish what I want to do. I'd like to find a method like `.splitlines()` to assign the first two lines of text in a multiline string into two separate variables. Then group the rest of the text in the string together in another variable.

The purpose is to have consistent data-sets to write to a .csv using the three variables as data for separate columns.

```
Title of a string       
Description of the string        

There are multiple lines under the second line in the string! 
There are multiple lines under the second line in the string!
There are multiple lines under the second line in the string!
```

Any guidance on the pythonic way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `islice`**

In addition to normal list slicing you can use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) which is more performant when generating slices of larger lists.

Code would look like this:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('input.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()


first_line_list = list(islice(data, 0, 1))
second_line_list = list(islice(data, 1, 2))
other_lines_list = list(islice(data, 2, None))

first_line_string = "".join(first_line_list)
second_line_string = "".join(second_line_list)
other_lines_string = "".join(other_lines_list)
```

However, you should keep in mind that the data source you read from is long enough. If it is not, it will raise a `StopIteration` error when using `islice()` or an `IndexError` when using normal list slicing.

---

**Using regex**

The OP asked for a list-less approach additionally in the comments below.
Since reading data from a file leads to a string and via string-handling to lists later on or directly to a list of read lines I suggested using a regex instead.

I cannot tell anything about performance comparison between list/string handling and regex operations. However, this should do the job:

```
import re

regex = '(?P<first>.+)(\n)(?P<second>.+)([\n]{2})(?P<rest>.+[\n])'

preg = re.compile(regex)

with open('input.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

match = re.search(regex, data, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

first_line = match.group('first')
second_line = match.group('second')
rest_lines = match.group('rest')
```

Comment: how would this look if I'm working with a multiline string, is there a way to avoid having to make a list then join said list?

Comment: I do not see any reason for avoiding lists since those are a very basic datatype in Python and their implementation is fast enough in most cases. The only approach I can think about without using lists is using regular expressions with matching groups which would be kind of nasty...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to split a large string into lines

```
lines = input_string.splitlines()
```

After that, you want to assign the first and second line to variables and the rest to another variable

```
title = lines[0]
description = lines[1]
rest = lines[2:]
```

If you want 'rest' to be a string, you can achieve that by joining it with  a newline character.

```
rest = '\n'.join(lines[2:])
```

A different, very fast option is:

```
lines = input_string.split('\n', maxsplit=2)  # This only separates the first to lines
title = lines[0]
description = lines[1]
rest = lines[2]
```

Comment: The OP would like to save the title and the description in a single multiline string.

Also, `rest` will return a list.